# How are Windows command lines represented by the OS?

Tags: windows, parsing, winapi, command-line

I'm struggling to understand how Windows handles command lines. MSDN documentation helps only slightly.

How are the following things related:

- `CreateProcessA()` and `CreateProcessW()` arguments `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine`
- `GetCommandLineA()` and `GetCommandLineW()` return values
- `WinMain()` and `wWinMain()` argument `lpCmdLine`
- `main()` and `wmain()` argument `argv`
- C global variables `__argc`, `__argv`, `__wargv`
- `CommandLineToArgvW()`
- Running an executable based on a command line typed into `cmd.exe` or PowerShell

In particular:

- How does Windows store the command lines of processes internally?
- Which one of the above is closest to that representation?
- Has the representation changed between Windows versions?
- Is the representation affected by codepage settings?
- Are there command lines that cannot be represented (in particular codepages, or at all) and what happens if you try to give them to `CreateProcess()`? (E.g. on Unix, a command line argument cannot have a null byte since the fundamental representation taken by `execve()` is an array of null-terminated byte strings.)
- `CreateProcess()` can take either `lpApplicationName` or `lpCommandLine` or both at the same time. If you give both, does ths OS combine them internally into one string that is then passed to the created process as its command line?

Related questions:

- [What is the Windows command line parameter encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465412/what-is-the-windows-command-line-parameter-encoding)
- [How to query a running process for its parameter list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520428/how-to-query-a-running-process-for-its-parameters-list-windows-c/6522047#6522047)

Comment: command line stored in user mode process memory, inside `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`. because string in utf-16 - it not affected by codepage settings

Comment: @rbm: Command lines are UTF-16 in the Windows NT line of products only. In 16-bit Windows and Win9x, the command line was ANSI encoded.

Comment: @IInspectable - think 16-bit Windows and Win9x already not actual

Comment: It helps to understand the context anyway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/ns-winternl-rtl_user_process_parameters says `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` has `ImagePathName` and `CommandLine` fields, both of type `UNICODE_STRING`. Do all of the functions/variables I listed derive their information from those fields via different routes? `UNICODE_STRING` seems like a simple string buffer with a fixed amount of spare capacity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_unicode_string

Comment: @Lassi, yes a `UNICODE_STRING` is fixed at 32767 UTF-16 ordinals (not necessarily characters -- could be surrogate pairs or combining codes), and `CreateProcessW` null terminates, so it's 32766. This means the command line is a poor choice for passing an arbitrary number of filenames, as opposed to a Unix `argv` array, which is one reason that Windows programs do their own wildcard expansion instead of relying on the shell to do it.

Comment: Is this right: WinNT stores all command lines as UTF-16 internally, and if you call `CreateProcessA()`, or get the command line from `GetCommandLineA()` or `WinMain` `lpCmdLine` or `main` `argv` or the global variable `__argv`, the WinAPI DLLs (or the C runtime library) internally convert between UTF-16 and the current codepage?

Comment: @rbm: One of the questions is: *"Has the representation changed between Windows versions?"* Historic background information is valuable in understanding, why there are symbols with competing character encodings in both the CRT and the Windows API. The fact that 16-bit Windows and Win9x are no longer supported is irrelevant.

Comment: Almost everything encoded with the active codepage is translated at runtime, with dynamically allocated strings in Windows 8+. It used to be static string buffers in most places, often at `MAX_PATH` plus a bit extra, but that's been gradually phased out over the past few versions. Nowadays in Windows 10 the system active codepage can even be UTF-8, and the per-process "activeCodePage" can be UTF-8. I'm observing a trend that the Windows API is reviving the multibyte string API (i.e. ANSI) for this use case to facilitate cross-platform application development. We'll see how it plays out.

Comment: Which functions would you recommend as currently being the most reliable way to get the command line of the calling process? Is it `GetCommandLineW()` followed by an optional `CommandLineToArgvW()` to split it? Interestingly, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew implies `GetCommandLineW()` cannot fail. It returns a null-terminated string, so some part of the system has to guard against `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` having nulls in the strings (unless those strings just get truncated at a null wchar).

Comment: The part of the system that guards against embedded nulls is `CreateProcess[AsUser]W`, since `lpCommandLine` is a null-terminated string. If you were to call `NtCreateUserProcess` directly it might accept a command-line with nulls because that's not a problem in NT, which uses counted strings. Anyway, you wouldn't call `NtCreateUserProcess` because additional work has to be done to ready a Windows process by messaging the session server, csrss.exe, so it's a moot point.

Comment: A Windows-only application would use `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` or simply rely on the CRT's argument parsing with the `wmain` entry point. For cross-platform development in Windows 10 1903+, we have the ability to set the "activeCodePage" to UTF-8, in which case using `main` with "ANSI" strings is also fine. It incurs the cost of runtime translation, but such apps are often doing that already because Unix programs almost always use `char` strings, and porting them to `wchar_t` would be expensive and move the cost of runtime translation to the Unix side.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers, I learned a ton! That already more or less covers the long list of interrelated questions I posted. Feel free to write up an answer if you want some rep :)